# Using chunk with relationships models query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to query a lot of rows with two models in a controller,
when i increase the number of days i get 500 error
I'm getting memory leakage and 500 response as result.

This is using laravel 5.8 and mysql, i have tried to get result chunk i don't understand where to insert it.

```php
       $inv = Inv::with(['telems' => function($query) use ($date) {
            $query->whereBetween('time',[Carbon::parse($date)->subDays(7), $date]);
        },'events' => function($query) use ($date){
            $query->whereBetween('time',[Carbon::parse($date)->subDays(7), $date])->get('code');
        }])->where('project' , '=', $id)->get();

        return $inv;
```

result should look like this

````
{
 key: value,
 key: value,
 telems: {thousands of timestamps},
 events: {thousands of timestamps}
}```
````

Comment: hey, you dont need to add get() in $query it automatically get

Comment: i don't think chunk is a good idea. Try skip() and take() methods equal to "limit" in sql ;)

Comment: I think your error comes from stackoverflow rather than memory leak.
Try running this portion of code only and tell me if it works: `$t = Telems::all(); $i = Inv::all();` - in other words, get all instances of both models, because if that doesn't crash, then you loading only a selection of the model entries isn't the issue either.

Comment: when i return $i and $t array i still get 500 error, maybe the tables are too big ? **edited the code as well

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: laravel 5.8 and mysql